# Get string in between many other strings [R]

Tags: r, regex

Here I want to extract the string part "wanted1part". I could do it like this:

```r
string <- "foo_bar_doo_xwanted1part_more_junk"
gsub("\\_.*", "", gsub(".*?_x", "", string))
#> [1] "wanted1part"
```

But I wanted hoping that maybe someone could suggest a one line solution?

Comment: What is the logic? first word that starts with `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with using `gsub`, you can use a capture group that is backreferenced in the replacement:

```
gsub('^.+_x(\\w+?)_.+$', '\\1', string, perl = TRUE)
```

The key here is to have the pattern match the whole string but to have a capture group, specified using parenthesis, match the part of the string you would like to keep. This group, here "(\\w+?)", can then replace the entire string when we reference it in the replacement.

I've found that using `str_extract` from `stringr` can make this kind of thing a easier as it allows me to avoid the use of capture groups.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, '(?<=_x)\\w+?(?=_)')
```

Here, I use a lookahead and lookbehind instead to identify the part of the string we want to extract.

Comment: oops. I modified the example so that the middle part includes a number.

Comment: No problem, see my updated solution.

Comment: That definitely works. Any thoughts on how to avoid using `stringr::str_extract`?

Comment: Sure thing, this is a little messy, but it works. I'll add it to my answer `gsub('^.+_x(\\w+?)_.+$', '\\1', string, perl = TRUE)`